# How can Linux find command delete mulitple file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

I have a file tree like:

```
.
├── 1
├── 2
├── 3
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
└── c.csv
```

now, I use command:

```
find . ! -name "*.txt" -delete
```

I can delete exclude  *.txt.

But now, I need to also exlcude c.csv.

Based on this I tried this command:

```
find . ! -name "*.txt|*.csv" -delete
```

But unfortunately, that command delete all files and folder.

So, How can I exclude multiple *.XXX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate the name predicate:

```
find . ! -name "*.txt" ! -name "*.csv" -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid:

```
find . ! -name "*.txt|*.csv" -delete
```

This is the correct way to write that (well, *one of equivalently correct* ways):

```
find . ! "(" -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.csv" ")" -delete
```

"Find and delete all files that are not named *.txt or *.csv"

Comment: What would De Morgan say about our two solutions

Comment: @Shloim: I put in "one of equivalently correct ways" :D